# SQL Server Query Error on WHERE

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

SQL Server 2005 via C# (VS 20015). Any idea why `WHERE` won't work?

SQL statement is:

```
SELECT 
    AA003Employee.idEmployee, 
    AA001Person.LastName, AA001Person.FirstName, 
    AA017JobTitle.JobTitle, AA017JobTitle.Department, 
    AA003Employee.Disabled 
FROM 
    AA003Employee 
JOIN 
    AA001Person ON AA003Employee.idPerson = AA001Person.idPerson 
JOIN 
    AA017JobTitle ON AA003Employee.idJobTitle = AA017JobTitle.idJobTitle 
ORDER BY 
    AA001Person.LastName ASC, AA001Person.FirstName ASC, 
    AA017JobTitle.JobTitle ASC 
WHERE 
    AA003Employee.Disabled = 'N';
```

Tried:

1. It works fine when omitting -> `WHERE AA003Employee.Disabled = 'N'`
2. It throws the error when I try replacing it with -> "... `WHERE Disabled = 'N'";`

Here is a screenshot of the error:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: `WHERE` goes directly after the `FROM` clause, before the `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is the placement of the `WHERE` clause.  SQL cares about the order of the clauses in statements.  But you should also learn to use table aliases:

```
SELECT e.idEmployee, p.LastName, p.FirstName, jt.JobTitle, jt.Department, e.Disabled
FROM AA003Employee e JOIN
     AA001Person p
     ON e.idPerson = p.idPerson JOIN
     AA017JobTitle jt
     ON e.idJobTitle = jt.idJobTitle
WHERE e.Disabled = 'N'
ORDER BY p.LastName ASC, p.FirstName ASC, jt.JobTitle ASC;
```

See?  The query is much easier to write and to read.

Answer (score 1):

Replace query with ,

```
SELECT AA003Employee.idEmployee, AA001Person.LastName, AA001Person.FirstName, AA017JobTitle.JobTitle, AA017JobTitle.Department, AA003Employee.Disabled 
FROM AA003Employee 
JOIN AA001Person ON AA003Employee.idPerson=AA001Person.idPerson 
JOIN AA017JobTitle ON AA003Employee.idJobTitle=AA017JobTitle.idJobTitle 
WHERE AA003Employee.Disabled = 'N' 
ORDER BY AA001Person.LastName ASC, AA001Person.FirstName ASC, AA017JobTitle.JobTitle ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace Query with below SQL Statement

```
SELECT 
    AA003Employee.idEmployee, 
    AA001Person.LastName, 
    AA001Person.FirstName, 
    AA017JobTitle.JobTitle, 
    AA017JobTitle.Department, 
    AA003Employee.Disabled 

FROM AA003Employee 

JOIN AA001Person ON AA003Employee.idPerson=AA001Person.idPerson 
JOIN AA017JobTitle ON AA003Employee.idJobTitle=AA017JobTitle.idJobTitle 

WHERE AA003Employee.Disabled = 'N';

ORDER BY AA001Person.LastName ASC, AA001Person.FirstName ASC, AA017JobTitle.JobTitle ASC
```